# Rails 404 error for html format, but no issue with json format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

This is puzzling me. I have a Rails application which, in production on Heroku, is returning 404 errors for many records, when requested as follows:

```
https://myapplication.heroku.com/records/500

The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
```

while the JSON version of the same page is fine:

```
https://myapplication.heroku.com/records/500.json
```

There are a few instances of model that work just fine with the regular HTML version:

```
https://myapplication.heroku.com/records/600
```

Here is the relevant part of config/routes.rb:

```
  resources :records do
    member do
      get 'revisions'
    end
  end
```

And here is the #show action of the records controller:

```
# GET /records/1
# GET /records/1.json
def show
  @r = Record.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @r }
  end
end
```

This was all working fine yesterday, but today I did some database migrations on the records table and a lot of other changes to records. What's puzzling me is that the JSON part works, and the records do exist. I even tried adding the following to routes.rb and moving it to the top of the file:

```
get 'records/:id', to: 'records#show', constraints: { :id => /\d/ }
```

But it did nothing. Appending `.html` to the GET request in URL bar does not do anything either.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** Here is [a gist](https://gist.github.com/alexcwatt/ed73568b134ef116d59b) with the Heroku log.

Comment: What does production logs show (log/production.log)? Check for any errors in there.

Comment: This is Heroku:

at=info method=GET path=/records/3174 host=applicaton.herokuapp.com request_id=b317273e-6697-407c-ac84-6fa647c879d8 fwd="98.219.178.236" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=247ms status=404 bytes=1012

I'm not sure what can be gathered from that...

Comment: Check out the last 50-100 lines from bottom of the logs and see if any errors. Also, you can upload it on Gist and share the link in the question.

Comment: I really do appreciate the help. I've scanned through it and can't find any errors. Here's [the gist](https://gist.github.com/alexcwatt/ed73568b134ef116d59b).

Comment: Do you have any kind of caching? perhaps it all doesn't work but the json responses are cached and therefore are still served from cache.

Comment: Tamer, good point. I don't remember having any caching at that level; but I just tried changing the ID of the record and resaving it, and I can load it with the new ID! Then switch back to old and it stops working.

Comment: Hmm... Still a bit stuck. The only things I can think of that could be caching are Memcachier and redistogo, and I flushed both of those. Also set `action_controller.perform_caching` to `false` in production. Still nothing. Can you think of any other places to check? I don't remember configuring this to cache. The only caching I remember configuring is Russian doll caching in some views.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Kirti and Tamer. After properly enabling logs, I figured this one out (see my answer below if interested).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would `refactor` your controller, like so:

```
#app/controllers/records_controller.rb
respond_to :html, :json

def show
  @r = Record.find params[:id]
  respond_with @r
end
```

---

Your code looks fine to me.... So I would suggest we take a deeper look into (asking some comments):

> This was all working fine yesterday, but today I did some database
>   migrations on the records table

Comment: Can you explain which migrations you performed & why (what are you trying to achieve?). I think you've probably caused some inconsistency in your `records` table

Comment: Thanks Rich. I actually just resolved the issue -- it was an issue with a view and another model, and I didn't realize that until Heroku support pointed out that my logging was not set to debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

I was using PaperTrail for Versions and in the view for `Record` called `User.find(@r.versions.last.whodunnit.to_i)`, but `@r.versions.last.whodunnit.to_i` was 0 and the user could not be found.

I was thrown by the 404 error because I thought it was somehow not finding the primary `Record` record in the database, when it was actually something else.

After [enabling logging](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails4#logging-and-assets), this was not hard to debug. (I thought I had enabled logging before, but apparently not.)

Thank you all for your help!